# Why the sisters dont have the same power than Railgun if they have exactly the same DNA?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index, a-certain-scientific-railgun, a-certain-scientific-accelerator

Railgun is level #5 esper, but her "sisters" only are level #2, #3 or #4, regardless they have exactly the same DNA. Why is this so?

Comment: Weren't they imperfect clones or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Tree Diagram showed it was actually impossible to clone a Level 5 "Railgun" which was the original plan

> Before mass production of the clones could begin, the simulation that the Tree Diagram produced showed that it was impossible to create a level 5 clone of Mikoto despite genetic manipulation and use of the Testament. It showed that the clones' specifications reached less than 1% of that of the real Mikoto's, which was equal to that of a level 2.

Source: [Radio Nose Project > Failure of the First Production Plan (1st Paragraph)](https://toarumajutsunoindex.fandom.com/wiki/Radio_Noise_Project#Failure_of_the_First_Production_Plan)

The original plan was to make "Railgun" clones for military purposes.

the Level 6 Shift program, the one to make Accelerator a Level 6, reused the previous work by calculating how many Level 5 "Railgun" it would take and then calculating the equivalent with the SISTERS

> However, the Level 6 Shift program – an experiment designed to make Accelerator, the strongest level 5 in Academy City reach level 6 – reused the project. The project began after Tree Diagram calculated that Accelerator killing Mikoto 128 times in battle, would allow him to achieve level 6; however, since 128 level 5 Mikoto clones could not be prepared, it was calculated by Tree Diagram that Accelerator killing 20,000 clones at level 2-3 would achieve the same results.

Source: [Radio Noise Project > Second Production Plan: Level 6 Shift (1st Paragraph)](https://toarumajutsunoindex.fandom.com/wiki/Radio_Noise_Project#Second_Production_Plan:_Level_6_Shift)

i suspect that the Level 2-3 range is because the Misaka Network is similar to the  Level Upper Network and Tree Diagram probably accounted for this (while [Last Order](https://toarumajutsunoindex.fandom.com/wiki/Last_Order) is listed as a Level 3 while all the other clones are listed as Level 2-3, given she was made as a fail-safe to stop the SISTERS i don't think she was planned to fight as her ID is 20001 and outside Tree Diagrams 20000 calculation)

however from the beginning the second plan was designed to fail anyway because

> Aleister Crowley purposely wanted it to fail so he could have the sister clones distributed all around the globe for the massive AIM-field, which was a crucial part to his plan to eliminate magic

---

> but her "sisters" only are level #2, #3 or #4

Actually the only Level 4 SISTER is [Misaka Worst](https://toarumajutsunoindex.fandom.com/wiki/Misaka_Worst) who was shown to be difference in physical appearances (as noted by the linked Wikia, Misaka Worst is taller and have a larger chest compared to the SISTERS or Misaka). Misaka Worst was also created after Index accidentally destroyed Orihime 1 and Tree Diagarma and outside the Level 6 Shift Program